# Boot freeze with Logitech Unifying Receiver

Tags: boot, usb, input-devices, logitech, logitech-unifying

I've bought an M570 mouse from Logitech. It runs plug and play with Ubuntu, but the system hangs on boot with the Logitech unify receiver inserted. I must unplug the USB receiver before booting and insert it again on the login screen. Nothing appears in syslog (it freezes at very early stage).

Note: Another Logitech receiver is plugged on my computer (Cordless keyboard receiver)

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:0059 NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c505 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse+Keyboard Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2304:0237 Pinnacle Systems, Inc. PCTV 73e [DiBcom DiB7000PC]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

**xinput --list**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What can I do to make these devices work without freezing?

Comment: Have you tried changing the USB port?

Comment: Yes, with no results

Comment: Solved ! You were right. Changing USB port on the same hub didn't solve freezing, but changing to the front panel USB port works.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the physical USB port that it is connected to on your computer. If it is in a hub, try moving the hub and/or the usb device itself.