# Logitech unifying receiver works only in one USB port in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mouse, 16.10, logitech-unifying

I have Ubuntu 16.10 (`4.8.0-42-generic`) on my Macbook Pro (11,5) and Logitech Performance MX mouse with unifying receiver.

The mouse works OK when the receiver is plugged in the USB port on the right side, but does not work in the other one.

`lsusb` detects it correctly.

When it works OK:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

When it does not work:

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

I've tried to reboot, of course.

It is not a hardware malfunction: the USB port works with USB keyboard and flash drive.

Moreover, when I boot in MacOS X, the mouse works OK with both USB ports.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You might see my previous answer to something similar... http://askubuntu.com/questions/884199/grub-freezes-when-logitech-unifying-receiver-plugged-in/884229#884229

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, when I needed to connect my Logitech Keyboard and Mouse through USB 3.0 HUB.

They worked well in windows, but for some reason didn't worked in Linux, even if the receiver was detected by linux, and appeared in the list of USB devices.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0100 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2115 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 17e9:6000 DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b5da Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Tried several things, nothing helped me.

The only that worked for me is upgrading Unified Receiver Firmware from this page: 
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032078393-Logitech-Response-to-Research-Findings

I needed to do it from windows, but after that upgrade it starts to work on linux + hub, and I notice also that periodic lags with keyboard were removed.