# Stuck on GNU GRUB screen: Dual Booted HP Spectre x360 13t

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 on my HP Spectre x360 13t. After installation, when I turn on the laptop, its always stuck on the purple GNU Grub 2.02 screen with a frozen countdown timer. I can't choose which OS to boot into, everything is just stuck. The only way I could choose which OS to boot into is by manually going into the BIOS every time I turn on the PC and choose a boot loader. Performing Grub repair from Ubuntu doesn't seem to help. Did anyone ever face a similar problem?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Its 18.04 @K7AAY. I have updated the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Grub freezes when logitech unifying receiver plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884199/grub-freezes-when-logitech-unifying-receiver-plugged-in)

This seems to be the problem. Without the dongle plugged in, it works totally fine.

Comment: Can confirm on my Spectre x360 this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I could choose which OS to boot into is by manually going into the BIOS every time I turn on the PC and choose a boot loader.

Does the Grub window appear and work properly if you do this? If so, it seems that changing the boot device in the BIOS would do the trick.

If that's not the case and Grub does not show up, but instead you are booted directly into Windows or Ubuntu. Then edit the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and remove `quiet` and `splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash"`. Leave the quotes and remember to change it back after everything is solved. Now reboot normally.

Disabling `quiet` causes the kernel to print errors, warnings and general information.
Disabling `splash`, disables the Ubuntu loading screen and displays system processes/warnings/errors instead. This should provide more information on what is happening.

Comment: Yes, when I do that and pick Ubuntu from the list, grub shows up and works properly. If I pick windows, it'll directly boot into windows. What exactly do you mean by changing the boot device? Can you please elaborate

Comment: (1/2) Well BIOS stands for basic input/output system. It manages the hard drive, keyboard, mouse, CD player, display, ram, etc. The BIOS loads the OS from the device (hard drive / USB / CD), but to do so it needs to know which device that is. At default, the BIOS is usually configured such that it first checks the USB ports, then the CD/DVD player and then the SSD/HDDs. Judging by the comment below about the Logitech unifying receiver, it tries to load stuff from it while this isn't possible. So you will need to change the default boot order.

Comment: (2/2) I cannot give the exact steps that you need to take, since with the introduction of the UEFI bios, every manufacturer tends to have a different layout. Enter the bios using 'Esc' key or one of the F-keys , then go through all the options/tabs to find the option 'boot order'. If you found it, change the boot order such that the boot device that did work for you is placed at the top. Hopefully this fixed it and please leave a like if it helped.